# Spring Boot requesting data by Id

Tags: java, spring-boot

Category.java

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "categories")
public class Category implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@NotNull
@Size(min = 5, max = 60)
@Column(name = "category", length = 50, unique = true)
private String category;

@OneToMany
private Set<Product> product;
```

}

Category Controller.java

```
@GetMapping("/category/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<List<Product>> getCategoryById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long categoryId) {
    List<Product> category = productRepository.findAllByCategoryId(categoryId);
    if (category == null) {
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(category);
}
```

ControllerRepositoy.java

```
@Repository
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category,Long>{

}
```

Products.Java

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 5, max = 60)
    @Column(name = "productName", length = 50, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String productName;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 10, max = 200)
    @Column(name = "description", length = 200, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @NotNull
    //@Pattern(regexp = "^[0-9]*$")
    @Size(min = 1, max = 10)
    @Column(name = "price", length = 10, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int price;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="product")
    private Category categoryId;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "imageURL", length = 500, nullable = false)
    private String image;

}
```

ProductController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/product")
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    ProductRepository productRepository;

    @GetMapping("/product")
    public List<Product> getAllNotes() {
        return productRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/product/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Optional<Product>> getProductById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long categoryID) {
        Optional<Product> product = productRepository.findById(categoryID);
        if(product == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(product);
    }

    @PostMapping("/product")
    public @Valid Product createProduct(@Valid @RequestBody Product product) {
        System.err.println(product);
        return productRepository.save(product);
    }


}
```

I want to query the products using the category Id. So I used productRepository in categoryController.

This is the code. When Id is given for a GET request, it shows a error. The error is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [1] did not match expected type [com.susl.Agroapi.model.Category (n/a)]
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: You're using an instance of `ProductRepository`, aren't you?

Comment: When asking about an exception, post the relevant code (ProductRepository and Product), and the complete stack trace of the exception. Note that a repository method returning a list will always return a list. Never null.

Comment: What is the class of `productRepository` you are using in the code? It has to be `ProductRepository` interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change code like below

Add Product entity to

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Category category;
```

Add Category entity to

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="category",cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)
private Set<Product> pr;
```

Make product repository like below

```
public interface ProductRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Product, Long>{
    List<Product> findAllProductByCategoryId(@Param("id")Long id);
}
```

Then you can call by Controller class using ProductRepository with `findAllProductByCategoryId({categoryId})`

Answer (score 0):

You still haven't posted the requested ProductRepository, but now that we at least have the Product entity, the error is most probably that the method should be named

```
findAllByCategoryIdId
```

since you want to search by `id` of the field `categoryId`.

Or you could (and should) rename the field `categoryId` to `category`, since that's what it is: a category, and not an ID.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you want to use CategoryRepository and using ProductRepository instead.

Create :

```
 @Autowired
 CategoryRepository categoryRepository;
```